# Right join on dateX between date1 and date2 (Sql) in DAX

Tags: sql, dax

In sql server I am able to create a view by right joining two of my tables on a datetime field. I want to know how to create the same view (table) using DAX. The Select statement I use when creating the view:

```sql
SELECT 
T1.identifier_value,
T1.Start_DateTime,
T1.End_DateTime,
T2.[DateTime],
T2.[hour]
FROM
Table1 T1 WITH (NOLOCK)
right join Table2 T2 WITH (NOLOCK) on T2.[DateTime] between T1.Start_DateTime and T1.End_DateTime
```

This results in the following table (In this example FakeID corresponds with one ID, so all records here have the same ID):

[image: Example of the view created in SQL]

I've tried using NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN in DAX and reversing the tables (trying to simulate a right join) using the following expression:

```
=NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        Table2;
            "DateTime";'Table2'[DateTime];
            "hour"; 'Table2'[hour]
        );
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        'Table1;
            "Identifier_value"; 'Table1'[identifier_value];
             "Start_DateTime"; 'Table1'[Start_DateTime];
            "End_DateTime"; 'Table1'[End_DateTime]
    )
)
```

As expected, this doesn't work because there is no common join column.

Is there a way to perform this join using DAX? I'm quite new to DAX, so if i'm doing something horribly wrong please let me know.

Comment: Where is your source data coming from? If you have a working SQL query and the data is in a database it would probably be easier to use that query to load into the model rather than creating it again with DAX.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DAX JOIN if a value is between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539765/dax-join-if-a-value-is-between-two-dates)

Comment: @BarneyL I can create the view in my personal database, however at some point i have to use the database my entire team works in. Since we only need the data in this way for this sepcific use-case we'd rather create this table within the project rather than putting an extra table into the database.
I'm taking a look at the link you sent now.

Comment: you wouldn't need to create a new table just use your query as a source for the data rather than a raw table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be best loaded in to the model via an SQL query but if it has to be done in DAX then I believe the only approach that will work is a cross join and a filter, this will get very slow for large numbers of rows.

```
Table =
FILTER(
    CROSSJOIN(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            Table2;
                "DateTime";'Table2'[DateTime];
                "hour"; 'Table2'[hour]
            ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            'Table1;
                "Identifier_value"; 'Table1'[identifier_value];
                 "Start_DateTime"; 'Table1'[Start_DateTime];
                "End_DateTime"; 'Table1'[End_DateTime]
        )
    ),
    'Table2'[DateTime] >= 'Table1'[Start_DateTime] &&
    'Table2'[DateTime] <= 'Table1'[End_DateTime]
)
```

Comment: I'm trying to use my query as a source by using the following power query:
`let
Source = #"SourceName"
#"Target" = Value.NativeQuery(Source, "MyQuery")
in
#"Target"
`

However, it keeps saying: Waiting for "SourceName"

Comment: In the meantime I tried to implement the DAX you wrote, but it crashed my visual studio (very large number of rows, so you called it). So I will try to either use the NativeQuery or will end up implementing it in the public database anyway if all else fails. Thanks for your help!